# error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘sum10’

Tags: c

//Write a C program to create an array with 10 float elements in a float array, find sum and
average using float pointer

```
#include<stdio.h>

float sum10(float);

int main()
{
    float array[3]={2.4,5.6,7.8};
    float sum,avg;
    sum=sum10(array);
    avg=sum/10;
    printf("Sum=%f \n",sum);
    printf("average=%f \n",avg);
    return 0;
}

float  sum10(float arr[])
{
    float s=arr[0]+arr[1]+arr[2];
    return s;

}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.   Please note that your question explicitly wants you to use “float POINTER” - ie, you must declare a variable of type `float *`, and use that to step through the array.

Comment: you declare `float sum10(float);` but then later define `float sum10(float arr[])`. Notice the difference

Answer (score 3):

The function declaration

```
float sum10(float);
```

is wrong. (The type of the argument differs from one in function definition)

You can copy & paste the first part of function definition and add a semicolon to create function declaration:

```
float  sum10(float arr[]);
```

Comment: `float sum10(float[]);` would also be ok.